# AngularJS Uncaught Type Error: cannot read property 'notify' of undefined && controller reads the html form values as NULL

Tags: json, angularjs, servlets

I am a beginner in AngularJS. I am implementing a CRUD application for practice.It has a single student table with name,password,email and phone fields.I am using MySQL as my database.
My application should work as follows:
The HTML page reads values of fields and passes these values to controller.js,which then calls the servlet.The servlet then connects to the database and inserts these values.Currently I am using $http.post() to call the servlet.The values should be passed to the servlet in JSON format.

According to what I have learnt,the values from HTML forms are read using $scope.But the values of form elements are null in my controller.js.
HERE is my HTML text input element:

```
<form name="regform" role="form" class="form-signin" action='InServlet'>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n1" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name"
           ng-model="std.name" ng-model-instant required autofocus/> 
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="n2" name="pwd" placeholder="Enter Password" required ng-model="std.pwd" ng-model-instant  maxlength="8"/>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="n3" name="mail" placeholder="Enter Email" required ng-model="std.mail" ng-model-instant />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n4" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" required minlength="10" maxlength="14" ng-model="std.phone" ng-model-instant />

  <button name="save" id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary"
            ng-disabled="regform.$invalid" 
            ng-Click="callInHttp(std)">
</form>
```

HERE is controller.js where I read the value of

```
angular.module('appcontrollers', [])
.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http,jsonFilter)
  {
  $scope.callInHttp=function($scope,std)
        {
           alert("std:"+$scope.std);   -->THIS DISPLAYS UNDEFINED
           .....
           /**CODE to call servlet**/
        }
  }
```

The error in the browser log says:
" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined ".

I need help regarding the following:
1)Please tell me where am I making the mistake in reading HTML form input values and how I should correct it.
2)How should I convert the HTML form input values into JSON format in angularjs?
3)How to send the JSON data to java servlet?
4)How should the Servlet convert the JSON data to strings so as to insert the data into database?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't require an action on forms. In fact, if you add it angular stops working on the form.

Remove the `action=""` and change it to `ng-submit="callInHttp()"`. You can then use `this` within your function to access the data from the form, i.e. `this.std.name`.

I don't think you need jsonFilter. When you pass an object to $http as the data, it converts it to JSON for you.

I'm not sure what you mean by a servlet - you mean a script on a server? That's another question in itself (unrelated to angular), however your JSON will be available in for example the $_POST vartiable of your script.

You should look into *angular services and factories*. That is where you should be doing ajax stuff, not from the controller.

Comment: I am using a Java Servlet to call the database and peform the CRUD operations on the database.Also,are we not supposed to use '$scope.element-name' in angularJS rather than 'this.element-name'?

Comment: I see. I can't help you there sorry. I have never heard of an angular site using Java for the backend.

Comment: What backends is it normally used with?

Comment: Thank you for the help.I have removed the action and placed ng-submit=callInHttp(std) and it worked! Controller.js declares the function as $scope.callInHttp=function(std){}.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the clarification you need:

1. Please tell me where am I making the mistake in reading HTML form
   input values and how I should correct it.

   Refer to tutorials on the internet to learn more about form submission. [This tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/forms.html) is informative.
2. How should I convert the HTML form input values into JSON format in
   angularjs? and
3. How to send the JSON data to java servlet?

   When you use `$http` service to pass on `GET` or `POST` methods, the request can be sent in JSON structure itself. 
   For example, a post request would look like this:

   `$http({ url: "URL", 
   method: "POST", 
   data: { 'param1' : param1value, 'param2' : param2value}).success(function(data){..})`

   Note that, the `data` being passed as the input has to be in the exact similar way as that of your object to which it's being mapped to. This is required for correct JSON mapping of the request to the object.
4. How should the Servlet convert the JSON data to strings so as to
   insert the data into database?

   You can use `GSON` library for this conversion. Example:

   ```
   Gson gson = new Gson();

   // get the JSON request into a StringBuilder object
   StringBuilder requestContent = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
   try {
       String line;
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           requestContent.append(line).append('\n');
       }
   } finally {
       reader.close();
   }

   // transform the input JSON request into YOUR_OBJECT object
   userDetails = gson.fromJson(requestContent.toString(), YOUR_OBJECT.class);
   ```

   In this example, `YOUR_OBJECT` is the object to which you would map the JSON request. As mentioned in the previous point, the structure (like the name of the variables in your objects will be same as the params being passed from the `$http` service from the frontend) of the JSON request must be the exact similar as that of your object. Else the mapping won't work correctly.

   Refer to [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for details on `Gson`.

Comment: I am using std variable to pass all the values of form elements.All my elements have ng-models named as 'std.name','std.pwd' and so on.So I suppose 'std' will contain all the values in the form.

Comment: I have edited my answer for your first question. Refer to some online tutorials and learn how to submit forms in Angular JS and how to access the data in controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help:) As per the tutorial,using $scope.myForm.firstName displays the value entered in textbox.In the case of my application,$scope.std.name displays 'undefined'.

Comment: Is the way I am using $scope the right way?I loaded the angularjs library files only in index.html and not in the partials.Can I load the library files in partials also,so that $scope is available in partials?Is it right to do that?

Comment: Where are you using "MyCtrl2" in your html? `ng-controller` is used to tell the HTML to refer to the correct controller from your JS file. Can you create a Plunkr or JSFiddle to show the full code? You can also go through this series of tutorials to get your all concepts clear: http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/26/angular-js-blog-series-table-of-content/

Comment: This HTML is a partial.In app.js I have specified the route to partial and the appropriate controller for the partial.

Comment: Sorry but really not understanding your point. Better create a Plunkr or JSFiddle and place your code there.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/7BEfiNWruh4TntUr4WIf This is the complete code.There is a problem in loading partials in plunker even though I have included the angular-route js file.In my code on NetBeans,Partials load,servlets are called but with null values in $scope.std.name.